# When is the depsgraph_update handler triggered? (and how does the depsgraph work? )

Tags: python, scripting

I've been looking at the depsgraph changes in the documentation [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Depsgraph), but I don't know if I understood it right: the dependency graph is a sort of diagram that links data blocks to each other so that blender updates only the necessary items, and not all the entire project, right?

So when is the `bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update` handler updated?

When changing any value in the project (so on any user input that changes a data-block), while rendering, when saving the project, when playing an animation...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could probably get an answer to your question by running Blender from the command line with one of these options:

[image: Command line depsgraph options]

Comment: Just decided to randomly check out the "unanswered" questions tab, only just now realized this was from 3 years ago. Lol anyways, hope it's helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: that will only display the debug messages, doesn't provide info on when it gets triggered.

Comment: Even when you use `--debug-depsgraph-time`?

Comment: taht one is just timed initialization info

Comment: In any case, OP isn't asking what time it's being updated as in "What is the GMT time the depsgraph is being updated?" they just want to know what actions cause the depsgraph to update. Running blender with `--debub-depsgraph` shows everytime it's updated, which seems to be essentially every time you do any single thing in a .blend file that would change it's save state.

Comment: It doesn't give you the triggers, only shows you when it updates. That means it's still up to the user to figure them out. (btw, you have a typo `debub` -> `debug`

Comment: Tbh, I ended up scrapping the project for which I needed this info. However, flagging this as accepted answer, as I don't see better answers.